# Is GTK a library or a language in itself

Tags: gtk

What exactly is GTK?

Is it some library, that is available for all the programming languages? i.e. I can `#include` it in C or maybe in Java I have the packets available that I can import?

Can someone describe it in easy terms?  thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GTK is not a language per se. It is primarily a toolkit (set of libraries) for C language. Quoting the description from [GTK Homepage](http://www.gtk.org) :

> GTK+, or the GIMP Toolkit, is a multi-platform toolkit for creating
>   graphical user interfaces. Offering a complete set of widgets, GTK+ is
>   suitable for projects ranging from small one-off tools to complete
>   application suites.

[Bindings for other languages](http://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php) exist which make the library available for various languages eg. Python, C++, Ruby etc. Most popular among them are [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org) (for [Python](http://www.python.org)) and [GTKmm](http://www.gtkmm.org) (for [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++)).  Infact GTK has been designed in a such a way that it makes creating bindings particularly easy.

> GTK+ is written in C but has been designed from the ground up to
>   support a wide range of languages, not only C/C++. Using GTK+ from
>   languages such as Perl and Python (especially in combination with the
>   Glade GUI builder) provides an effective method of rapid application
>   development.

GTK does introduce various [object oriented features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) for C programmers which are lacking in the core language.

Also efforts have been made to make a new language [Vala](https://live.gnome.org/Vala) that leverages the aforementioned object oriented features ([GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/)) along with a multitude of other object oriented functionalities and memory management features. Vala compiles down to C code. As you might expect it is popular primarily among Gnome developers.

Answer (score 2):

GTK+ is a toolkit to build graphical user interfaces. As such it is a library based on the [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) and [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/) libraries. Because of GObject and its introspection mechanism, there is quite a [big number](https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection/Users) of language bindings.

In short:

- Use the JGIR bindings for Java
- Use the GTK+ library as it is for C

Answer (score 0):

GTK is a library written in and for C. It has bindings for many other languages (including Java). So yes, once you've installed it (and, if you want to use it in Java, the Java bindings), you can just `#include` the appropriate headers in C or `import` the classes in Java and then start using it.

Comment: I am on an ubuntu system, do I need to explicitly install anything, or can I just use the library and start using the functions? Thanks.

Comment: @Sahil For C, you'll need to install the GTK headers (the binaries will already be installed). Should be something like gtk-dev or gtk3-dev - something with "dev" in its name at least. If you want to use Java, you'll have to install the Java bindings.

Comment: Yeah, I will be working with C only. How can I install the headers? Sorry new to the whole system. Thanks

Comment: @Sahil `sudo apt-get install gtk-dev` or whatever the package name is.